# Empty table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, cell

. This function is not called so i have an empty tableview how i can fix that ? I checked it using a print and the print doesn't
 appear

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : feedsviewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedsviewTableViewCell", for:indexPath) as! feedsviewTableViewCell
     print("did call")

    // Configure the cell...
   let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - indexPath .row]["text"] as! String

   // let post =   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in self.posts[(self.posts.count-1) - indexPath .row]["text"] as! String

        //print((snapshot.value as! String))


cell.configure(nil, post:post,name: self.loggedinuserdata!["name"]  as! String)



   return cell

}
```

.This is the viewdidload 
 self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        self.databaseref.child("users").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
            (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

```
        self.loggedinuserdata = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.databaseref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot ) in




            self.posts.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)


            self.feeds.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row : 0 ,section : 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }) {(error) in

            print(error.localizedDescription)


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the tableview delegate set, kindly check by putting a print statement in cellForRow to test whether it is getting called

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. Maybe try to clear up the post a bit and try to be as possible about your question.

Comment: @VIP-DEV  i added it the print doesn't appear so you are right the function is not called what can i do?

Comment: If the tablview is in storyboard, try to connect the delegate or else set it in viewDidLoad

Comment: may you provide an example please @VIP-DEV

Comment: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: Is your tableview created in storyboard or programmatically, so that we can approach towards solution.

Comment: yes it is created in the storyboard